# Best practice for letting non-root user (ww-data) edit a NGINX vhost

Tags: security, nginx, vhost

I'm confronted with a scenario where I have to let users edit their vhost through a GUI written in PHP. The `www-data` user has already the necessary `sudo` entry to restart NGINX.

Now I'm wondering what the best approach would be to let `www-data` write to a certain vhost. I think granting him write rights to `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` would not be such a good idea. Should I else put the vhost in the home directory of `www-data` and link from `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/vhost` to it?

What would be the best/most secure way to grant `www-data` access to edit a certain NGINX vhost file?

Comment: Don't. www-data should not have rights to either (re)start the service or edit things around for security reasons. I would rethink that security model.

Comment: Ok, but how to manage that from GUI then? How do server management panels implement this function? I know it's not good, but I'm searching for the most harmless solution.

Comment: Why do you need this? What is the exact scenario? Do you sell storage dedicated to homepage and your clients need this?